# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when running ASP.NET Core WebApi on IIS 7.5, but working correctly on IIS 8.5 and 10

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, iis-7.5

I've added CORS to my .NET Core WebApi and it's works just fine when running on IIS 8.5 and 10, but whenever I run it on IIS 7.5 I get ..

> Fetch API cannot load .. Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resourse. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. ..

I've tried tried switching from a specific origin to allowing any origin as well as adding this to my web.config:

```
 <system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

Is there some extra step I need to take in order to get it running on IIS 7.5?

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory )
    {
        ...
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication( GetJwtBearerOptions() );
        app.UseCors( ConfigureCors );
        app.UseExceptionHandler( ConfigureExceptionHandler );
        app.UseMvc();
    }

    private static void ConfigureCors( CorsPolicyBuilder builder )
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            //.WithOrigins( Configuration.GetSection( "Client" )["Url"] )
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
        // Add framework services
        services.AddOptions();
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>( Configuration );
        services.AddCors(); // obsolete?
        services.AddMvc( SetupMvcOptions )
            .AddJsonOptions( SetupMvcJsonOptions );
        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>( ConfigureJwtIssuerOptions );
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\Web.Services.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 90bd8dc9-484b-42c7-8074-e02397de9689-->
```

Comment: How about adding the same CORS policy to `services.AddCors();`?

Comment: did you ever get this working?